# If $\operatorname{ker}\varphi = \operatorname{ker}\psi$, then $\operatorname{im}\varphi=\operatorname{im}\psi$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite group $G$, let $\varphi: G \to G$ be a homomorphism and define another homomorphism $\psi: G \to G$ given by $\psi(x)=\varphi(\varphi(x))$. Then if $\operatorname{ker}\varphi = \operatorname{ker}\psi$, show that $\operatorname{im}\varphi=\operatorname{im}\psi$.

I have already shown the inclusion $\operatorname{im}\psi \subseteq\operatorname{im}\varphi$, but the other one is giving me trouble. Here is my work so far:

By the first isomorphism theorem and Lagrange's theorem, we have that $\lvert \operatorname{im}\varphi\rvert = \lvert \operatorname{im}\psi\rvert$, with both being finite. We observe that $\varphi: \operatorname{im}\varphi\to \operatorname{im}\psi$ is surjective by the definition of $\psi$. Since both sets are finite of the same size, it is a bijection. Then it has an inverse, $\varphi^{-1}$.
Let $y \in \operatorname{im}\phi$, so $y=\varphi(x)$. Then we can do the following manipulations: $y=\varphi(x)=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(\varphi(x)))=\varphi(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x))=\psi(\varphi^{-1}(x))$ and thus $y\in \operatorname{im}\psi$.

Now obviously the last manipulations do not work since $\varphi^{-1}(x)$ might not exist, since we have only shown it was bijective from $\operatorname{im}\varphi$ to $\operatorname{im}\psi$.
Can anyone help clean up this proof or suggest an alternative way forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is finite here. Since $\operatorname{im}(\psi) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(\varphi)$, the fact they have the same order implies equality.

Comment: Oh right, of course. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, it doesn't work if you drop finiteness, just consider $G = \mathbb{Z}$, and $\varphi(x) = 2 x$.

Comment: But is that a homomorphism?

Comment: Sure, of course this is $\mathbb{Z}$ as an *additive* group.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot it was additive, thanks :)